# Expand Fields and Items in one call and filter the expanded

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, filter

What i am trying to do is to get all lists and from all lists expand fields and items. Then filter some fields, and get all items (and not only first 100)

```
/_api/Web/Lists?$select=Title, Id, Hidden&$filter=(Hidden eq false)&$orderby=Title asc&$expand=Fields,Items
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Your query is working fine. I dont find any problem in it. What actually do you need?

Comment: Like i have it works but i dont know how i can change it to filter Fields,and how to expand more than just 100 Items , because like it is it gets all Fields,and it gets  only the top 100 items.